# 'The constructor ServletRegistrationBean(FacesServlet, String) is undefined' while trying to use JSF 2.1 in Spring Boot 3.2

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

Hi I have created a new Spring boot Project for learning purpose and included JSF. Below specified the version of my project

Sping boot - 3.2.2
Java -17
JSF

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

While compiling I am getting error like
"The constructor ServletRegistrationBean(FacesServlet, String) is undefined"

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
       return  new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet,"*.jsf");
    }   
}
```

I don't know why this error is coming. Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance

I tried with changing the version of spring boot. at the time application is not running.

I wanted to create an xhtml page with user entered details and display it in the same page.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.2 is JakartaEE, the JSF version you are using is incompatible with that. Which is showing due to the inclusion of the `javax.servlet-api` which you probably added due to classnotfound issues with what you have now.

Comment: can you tell me which jsf version is compatible with Spring boot 3.2.2 @M.Deinum

Comment: One that falls under the JakartaEE umbrella. Which that is I have no idea, I have a healthy dislike for JSF and stopped bothering. Probably something in the 3.x range.  You could check https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/ for version, use a JakartEE 9 or higher compatible version. Or don't use JSF but rather something like Thymeleaf with HTMX (but that is person preference).

Comment: Thank you for helping. It worked I included <b>jakarta.faces-api</b> version <b>4.0.1</b>. Thank you very much @M.Deinum

Comment: *"Spring Boot 3.2 is JakartaEE"* is an incorrect statement. It isn't at all provided by Jakarta EE implementations. Rather say "Spring Boot 3.2 uses Jakarta EE dependencies" or perhaps "Spring Boot 3.2 is Jakartified".

Comment: Correct, I should have written that it requires JakartaEE compatible libraries (which I normally do. Spring nor Spring Boot is a JakartaEE implementation).